# how i can get Object Id from Azure using Java API or other languages?

Tags: java, azure

[image]
i want to get this Microsoft Azure User Object Id from my Java Program which runs in my local server

i read the document about Azure usage, but not solve my problem

Comment: You can install Microsoft Graph Java SDK and run **[this](https://i.imgur.com/qnrzpPe.png)** query: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user_UPN?$select=id`

Answer (score 0):

> how i can get Object Id from Azure using Java API or other languages?

After reproducing from my end, I could able to make this work using PowerShell. Below is the script that worked for me.

```
$ObjectId = Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq '<YourDisplayName>'"
$ObjectId.ObjectId
```

**NOTE:** Make sure you use `Connect-AzureAD` before running the script

*RESULTS :*

[image]